# Android Google Places API Review

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

***APPLICATION***
    My application displays markers near my current location(which is working perfectly). After that the person can click the marker so that a windows pops up describing that particular location. Once the person clicks the on popup a review activity starts.

***PROBLEM***
    My Review Activity displays the name, address, contact, website, rating, reviews from users about that location. Everything works fine for some place, but doesn't for some.

This is my Code.java

```
    TextView addressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressText);
    TextView contactText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactText);
    TextView websiteText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.websiteText);

    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONObject completeDesc = json.getJSONObject("result");
    addressText.setText(completeDesc.getString("vicinity"));
    contactText.setText(completeDesc.getString("formatted_phone_number"));
    websiteText.setText(completeDesc.getString("website"));

    Double ratStar = completeDesc.getDouble("rating");

    JSONArray photo = json.getJSONArray("photos");
    JSONObject photoDesc = photo.getJSONObject(0);
    String photoRef = photoDesc.getString("photo_reference");

    checkStarCondition(ratStar);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.reviewInfo);
    JSONArray reviewArray = completeDesc.getJSONArray("reviews");

    if ( reviewArray.length() > 0 ) {
        TextView noReview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noReview);
        noReview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < reviewArray.length(); ++i) {
        TextView user = new TextView(ReviewActivity.this);
        TextView comment = new TextView(ReviewActivity.this);
        TextView linebreak = new TextView(ReviewActivity.this);

        JSONObject jObj = reviewArray.getJSONObject(i);
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        user.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        user.setText(jObj.getString("author_name"));
        user.setTextSize(18);
        user.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        comment.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        comment.setText(jObj.getString("text"));
        comment.setTextSize(14);

        linebreak.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linebreak.setText("           ");

        layout.addView(user);
        layout.addView(comment);
        layout.addView(linebreak);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

review_activty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mazik.ahmed.funkyproject.ReviewActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_store"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ratingStar"
            android:src="@drawable/star00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_name"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/nameText"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_address"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Address"
                android:id="@+id/addressText"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_call"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Contact"
                android:id="@+id/contactText"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_web"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Website"
                android:id="@+id/websiteText"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Reviews"
            android:id="@+id/reviewText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/reviewInfo"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="No Review Available"
            android:id="@+id/noReview"
            android:textColor="#CCC"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem that i am facing is that for some places the data that this api fetches is perfectly working but it fails on other places in some scenario even tho google maps shows rating and reviews for that location.

Can someone help me in where i am going wrong?

Comment: Have you cleared the previous place from the memory when you searched for newer one??

Comment: You're ignoring the `status` and `error_message` fields.  You should check `json.getString("status")` equals "OK".  If it doesn't, then json.getJSONObject("result") will be empty, and `status` (and, if present, `error_message`) will tell you why.  E.g. maybe you're over quota.